# Don't work yum update (yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue)

Tags: centos, yum

I have installed things successful via yum on centos 7. Then I install epel repo (`yum install epel-release` ) and always give me followings error and after that I couldn't install anything

```
 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
        yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

 4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

 5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

I have searched a lot on the internet but I couldn't find solution. Some people maybe from proxy. even if I added my proxy information to yum.conf, but again I failed.

Then I want to check that If I delete epel repo then probably It may works and I deleted epel-repo from system after that I could install.

Please help me I spent this issues two days

Comment: can you post the error you got ?

Comment: I have already posted this.....part of above

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown), and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

Comment: Do you still get the same error after running `yum clean metadata`?

Comment: I just uncommenting all baseurls in /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo read more here:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/centos-111/centos-yum-update-depency-problem-4175541770/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you have discovered, the package of epel-release is causing the issue. If you haven't already:

```
# yum remove epel-release
```

Then install the EPEL Repo with the following (requires wget package):

```
# wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/e/epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
# rpm -ivh epel-release-7-9.noarch.rpm
```

From there you should be able to do yum update without any issues.

Comment: Gave me same error

Comment: its giving a 404 error

Comment: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-extras-x86_64/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm.html

Answer (score 9):

I just had this issue with fresh CentOS 7.6

Solution was simple:

- Don't remove package `epel-release` (Install it if you have already removed it)
- Edit the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`
- In the first section (`[epel]`):

  - Comment `metalink=https://...`
  - Uncomment `baseurl=http://...`

This solved the issue for me.

Comment: It worked, thanks. In my case I found this problem using centos 7 image in a docker container. Epel-release required to install ansible.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add your DNS servers to `/etc/resolv.conf` so it can know the hosts in the repo, for example in my case (google DNS is enough):

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf

# Generated by NetworkManager

nameserver 192.168.1.128 # local DNS

nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Log in as `root` or use `sudo` and then:

```
#ONBOOT=no
#dhclient
#yum update
```

I hope it will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered this issue and root cause for this issue was yum repository was not accessible to the building docker image. So I have to change my network policy of my kubernetes cluster(since I was working on kubernetes project).

Answer (score 0):

I was NOT able to fix the problem, but figured eventually that specific packages can be installed directly from their original repository.

So, for example in my case, I was trying to simply install **unzip** using

```
yum install unzip
```

but ran into the same problem stating:

> One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown)

The resolution was to install directly from the repo:

```
sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/unzip-6.0-21.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Notice I am using cento 7 and x86_64 architecture.

You should browse and select your own configuration according to the system you're using.